# How to get the updated state in setState callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a code scenario where I need get the updated state in the setState callback. Like below :

```
this.setState({name : "xyz"}, () => {
  //I want the updated state here where I need to get the this.state.name should be "xyz"
})
```

Comment: yes, that is what the callback is used for. Are you having an issue accessing `this.state.name` there?

Comment: so whats the problem ? arent you getting the updated state there?

Comment: if you use `this.state` in the callback, it should be the updated state: https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Comment: You can access updated state in callback or you can acess updated state in componentDidUpdate lifecycle

Comment: @Agney It works, I was having something which was changing the reference of this.state

Comment: You can either use a callback to update state like this.setState(currentState=>{ return a state update based on currentState }) or you can use componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the updated state after setting a state is same as described in question.

```
this.setState({name : "xyz"}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.name)
});
```

*I asked this question as I had some issues in my function and was unable to get the updated state.*

Answer (score -1):

Use componentDidUpdate() to get updated state and props values.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      console.log(this.state, prevState);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @abhijit The question is on getting the updated state in callback.

Comment: @ShashankMalviya Correct, Generally you should have get updated state in the callback method. But you agreed in previous comments `I was having something which was changing the reference of this.state –` and the issue is not clear from your given code snippet. 
Hence to get over your issue I have suggested to use componentDidUpdate().